# Find what Action is called by a Button in interface builder in debug mode

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am debugging a huge project that I did not create and has no documentation. 
I am using the Debug View Hierarchy to stop the execution on views that need to be modified and just need to find out what view controller is responsible for the view and what actions are called by the interface.

How can I do that?

The view hierarchy only shows generic classes but not the specific classes in the project.
I can print the description of a button for example but that only gives me the memory address and the frame. Also, printing superview only gives me another memory address and frame.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kept trying the console and a few other posts and I found a solution:

First, print button description by right clicking it ( should work with any view )

```
    <UIButton: 0x7feefe5e20c0; frame = (17 266.5; 105 30); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000236520>>
```

second, use button address in console "0x7feefe5e20c0" to print all targets for the button

```
po [0x7feefe5e20c0 allTargets]
<ViewControllerClass: 0x7feefe5de7b0>
```

Now "ViewControllerClass" is already closer to what I need, it's the view controller owning the view that's containing my button

third print all control events for the button

```
(lldb) po [0x7feefe5e20c0 allControlEvents]
0x0000000000000040
```

and at last print button actions for target for control event

```
(lldb) po [0x7feefe5e20c0 actionsForTarget:0x7feefe5de7b0 forControlEvent:0x0000000000000040]
<__NSArrayM 0x7fef00078040>(
    actionCalledByBytton:
)
```

which gives me "actionCalledByBytton" the action invoked by the button on the "ViewControllerClass"

Tadaa! Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the button in interface builder. The actions should be listed under `Send Events`.

Also it is possible to add actions programmatically using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`

Comment: Xcode is in debug view hierarchy mode, not edit mode, right clicking only allows me to print description of view and a few more view options.

Comment: Can't you exit debug hierarchy mode with the `Continue program execution` button? The third from the left in the bottom panel.

Answer (score 0):

If your button has text in it, you can search the button's text in Find Navigator and have some prediction and if you have a image on the button, you can find the image name in assets.By this both you can minimise the search.
If you find any Label which contain a static text, go search for the text! May be this may help you!